# How does R+-Tree manages intersecting objects?

Tags: r-tree

Lets suppose in R-Tree we can hold maximum 4 elements in a leaf. Does it makes impossible to index more than 4 objects having common overlapping part? See the picture: all the 5 objects share the region covered by object 5. In R+-Tree internal nodes cannot overlap, so 4-leafs-R+-tree cannot have such a node that covers object 5 correctly. Is that correct? How this is handled in real GIS systems where many objects may have massively intersecting MBRs (Minimum Bounding Rect)? (The simplest idea is to have enough leaf capacity).

[image: The 5 overlapping objects]

Comment: The R+-tree is not very commonly used. I'm not aware of any "real GIS" using it: Having multiple copies of the same record is not very convenient for dynamic databases because it makes deletions and updates more expensive. But other than that, I believe you are right: the R+-tree conditions may be unsatisfiable...

Answer (score 1):

Let bounding boxes overlap - that's the key idea of r-trees.  If you do that everything works fine, but for some reason it bothers people.